# Multiple CURL's in a single shell script file

Tags: linux, curl

I am trying to execute a `.sh` file on a Linux server.

Below is my .sh fie

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8091/holding/EDDB7A753953C6AD9/CLIENT0/1?opsFlag=false &
curl -X POST http://localhost:8091/holding/28C273C43FC4E8E9D/CLIENT0/2?opsFlag=false &
curl -X POST http://localhost:8091/holding/D366AF1C366F202FA/CLIENT0/3?opsFlag=false &
curl -X POST http://localhost:8091/holding/8FE75B151CCCAD19A/CLIENT0/4?opsFlag=false
```

However, I am getting an error

```
[\abhi@datadb8888]$ sh file.sh
: command not foundne 1:
: command not foundne 2:
: command not foundne 3:
: command not foundne 4:
...
```

I have tried my file both with and without `&` at the end of the line but it still throws a different error.

Comment: @OlafDietsche thanks for that I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this issue out, apparently, windows and Unix/Linux recognize \r very differently which let to these issues.

I was creating the file in windows and executing it in my Linux based remote server.

To resolve this I have used `dos2unix` command in windows to covert the file in a way that Unix/Linux will not have an issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the quote to the url, hope this can help you:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8091/holding/EDDB7A753953C6AD9/CLIENT0/1?opsFlag=false"
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8091/holding/28C273C43FC4E8E9D/CLIENT0/2?opsFlag=false"
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8091/holding/D366AF1C366F202FA/CLIENT0/3?opsFlag=false"
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8091/holding/8FE75B151CCCAD19A/CLIENT0/4?opsFlag=false"
```

Comment: Now I am getting 'curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL'

Comment: got it the issue was due to how Windows and Unix/Linux recognize \r, used dos2unix file.sh to convert the file